# Can I attach a Stripe PaymentMethod to a Customer several hours after creating the PaymentMethod?

Tags: stripe-payments

When a user registers on my site, a pending registration object is created. The user must validate their email for an account object to be created.

I'd like to collect the user's payment information when they register but wait to create the `Customer` object until they actually validate their email and have an account. Is this possible? And is there a maximum amount of time that can elapse before I attach the `PaymentMethod` to a customer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is definitely possible. The best option here is to create a `SetupIntent` that will let you collect their payment details securely. Once the SetupIntent is completed successfully you will get a valid PaymentMethod that you can then attach to a new customer in the future without a specific time limit.

You can read more about this in Stripe's docs: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/setup-intents